# Disallow directory at root only, and not elsewhere using robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

I need to exclude anything that contains `/page/` but only at root:

Disallowed: `example.com/page/1`

Allowed: `example.com/category/page/1`

How to safely write this in *robots.txt*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost have it.

This is the correct syntax:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /page
```

**Explanation:**

The `Disallow:` directive is *relative-to-root*.

So the very first `/` in that directive indicates the root folder of your website.

Consequently, the directive `Disallow: /page` will disallow:

```
/page/alpha/
/page/beta/
/page/gamma/
```

but it *won't* disallow:

```
/aleph/page/
/bet/page/
/gimel/page/
```

because the latter three paths don't begin with `/page/`.